Alternative paper map for Michelin North & West Africa 741
Is there an alternative paper map to the Michelin North & West Africa 741 map? With similar scale (1cm -> 40km)

I asked Michelin and they said "Celui-ci ayant été arrêté." (I think that means it is not being printed any more.)
There are some online shops that say they still have copies (at reasonable-ish prices).
But I was wondering if there is any alternatives from other publishing houses.
Only alternative I can think of : make photocopies of the local libraries atlas.

If you can get it elsewhere at reasonable prices, why are you looking for an alternative?  What differences are you looking for that aren't in the one you can already get?

The map dealer Stanfords (no affiliation) has over 1000 maps of various parts of Africa and good filters to enable you to search by scale and other properties. The most similar to the Michelin map that I found by briefly poking around is the Africa Western ITMB map, at a scale of 1:3,200,000, fairly similar to the 1:4,000,000 map you post above, but you might want to look further to see if there is something that better meets your needs.
Of course, many travelers these days use digital maps instead of paper. You could consider e.g. the Organic Maps app (again, no affiliation), free on Android and iOS, which lets you download maps before traveling for storage offline, if you are concerned about being able to access the maps while traveling through areas with limited or no mobile data service.

Note that Google Maps and Apple Maps also allow downloading maps for offline use.

@jcaron Those are, of course, good alternatives for many uses, but as far as I'm aware they don't let you download big regions like "all of northwestern Africa".
